# GWT RequestFactory entity type initialization

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I was looking over the DynatableRF example and I was wondering why in SummaryWidget when you create a new Person instance the subfields like address and schedule are not auto-populated. Is there a better way than to manually instantiate a new instance of every non-primitive subfield down the tree?

Answer (score 0):

The framework can't auto-populate subfields because it won't know if you want instances in those fields or you want them to be null. You want different things in different circumstances.

It sounds like what you are asking for is Dependency Injection in which case the [GIN (GWT INjection)](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) project can help.